# Composting teabags?

Tags: recycling, composting

I have a problem during waste segregation with a small, but often used product, namely teabags.

It's a bit of organic matter wrapped in paper, with a thread and staple. The organic part is easy - it belongs in compost. Paper is a bit more difficult, but compost bags in Germany are made of paper anyway.

But what with thread? It should compost as well; it's organic matter, too. But the staple makes things problematic. Should I simply remove them and throw the rest into composting matter, or can I simply ignore it because it will corrode anyway?

Comment: I share your concern.  We have so many choices for tea at my stores that I simply choose to **only** buy bags without staples, and with paper, not plastic, wrapping.  Good question, though.

Comment: Is it really a problem to compost the staple as well? Is is a small bit of steel, which will take a while (a couple of decades, maybe) to rust and decompose, but the iron oxide given off doesn't sound very harmful. A staple-size bit of iron is much less of a problem than stones. That said, I usually buy loose tea and use a pot with a built-in sieve.

Comment: @Earthling, I would guess that it's not a big problem.  The bigger reason I tend to avoid it is if you use the compost yourself (vs. sending it to a large city facility).  I like to garden without gloves, and don't like the thought of running my hands through sharp, rusty metal objects.  From a pollution or waste standpoint, I agree that it seems like a small impact.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Interestingly, it appears that **teabag paper [commonly includes "food-grade" polypropylene](http://www.recyclethis.co.uk/20110602/composting-teabags)**, which doesn't readily decompose. The link contains a quote from Tetley, amongst others:

> The material used to make the actual tea bag is a mixture of mainly
>   cellulose fibres and a small amount of polypropylene fibres to give
>   the heat seal. Under normal composting conditions the cellulose fibres
>   will break down, as will the tea, leaving the very small polypropylene
>   fibres which are normally so small they are not seen.

Learning the above isn't going to stop me composting teabags, but the brand of tea may make a difference as to the severity of the problem. I found [this description](http://alice-in-blogland.blogspot.co.nz/2007/05/composting-tea-bags.html) of substantial frustration with the remaining fibres left after composting (please ignore the advice from the tea company to burn them instead! Burning plastic is a terrible idea). I would also draw the line at composting nylon teabags (I wouldn't buy them either), which thankfully doesn't appear to have caught on since [this 2007 article discussing the concept](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/news/uknews/1568610/Nylon-teabags-set-to-let-the-flavour-flood-out.html) was published.

**I wouldn't worry too much about a few steel staples in my compost**; I'm confident they will readily corrode and won't make any significant difference to the chemical composition of my garden, or my health (after eating the harvest). Iron oxides are [already generally abundant in soil](http://www.research.vt.edu/resmag/sciencecol/iron.html).

That leaves the paper tag and a piece of thread to consider.  The paper tag, provided it's not coated with plastic, should be ok in small quantities.

If the thread is cotton, it will easily decompose. After a few careful web searches, I didn't manage to find evidence that anything else is used.

[Wikipedia notes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tea_bag) that corn starch ("[Soilon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Soilon)") and silk are also used for tea bags, which don't appear to include polypropylene.

All that said, I can taste the difference between tea bag tea and loose leaf tea; the **loose leaf tea tastes better, and is easy to handle with a one-serving strainer**. Just don't gulp the dregs at the bottom of the cup!

Comment: And I'll go ahead and spell out the other benefits of loose leaf tea:
- overall packaging efficiency
- avoids staples and food-grade polypropylene altogether
- all other things equal, cheaper on a per serving basis

Excellent answer, Highly Irregular.

Comment: At each step of the manufacturing process, undesirable flavors can be introduced or desirable ones removed. Great write-up and conclusion.

Comment: buying herbal "tea" infusions as loose leaf can be hard to impossible, unfortunately. The pure ones are usually doable, peppermint, chamomile etc, but I like the fruity ones too and those... DIY is very hard. So I have jars of some where I can find them, and teabags for the rest. Also, you need a really, really fine infuser for chamomile, the stamens are tiny.

Answer (score 8):

In my household, we tear off the staples before composting. Happily, many teabags are made without them, so you can also only buy from manufacturers that have eliminated that little item.